# Doctrine Entities and traits. Right way

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, traits

I have a Comment entity (for user comments) and I want to add a new feature (Commentable) in my old entities.
I created a trait Commentable:

```
trait Commentable
{
    /**
     * List of comments
     *
     * @var Comment[]|ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment")
     */
    protected $comments;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get Comments
     *
     * @return Comment[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getComments()
    {
        return $this->comments;
    }

    /**
     * Add comment to the entity
     *
     * @param Comment $comment
     */
    public function addComment(Comment $comment)
    {
        $this->comments->add($comment);
    }
}
```

and in the old entities I do something like this:

```
class Image
{
    use Commentable {
        Commentable::__construct as private __commentableConstruct;
    }

    /** some stuff **/
}
```

The Comment class looks like:

```
class Comment
{
    /**
     * Identifier
     *
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Comment owner
     *
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Comment content
     *
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $content;

    /**
     * @var Image
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Image", inversedBy="comments")
     */
    protected $image;
    /** all the classes using Commentable **/

    /** some stuff */
}
```

I think the idea is not bad. I can create new behaviours and easily add it to entities.
But I don't like the idea on the Comment entity. Adding all the classes using the commentable trait is not 'usefull'.
I'm receiving this error... but I don't know how I can fix that with traits:

```
OneToMany mapping on field 'comments' requires the 'mappedBy' attribute.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the problem using

```
trait Commentable
{
    /**
     * List of comments
     *
     * @var Comment[]|ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="XXXX\Entity\Comment")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"createdAt" = "DESC"})
     */
    protected $comments;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get Comments
     *
     * @return Comment[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getComments()
    {
        return $this->comments;
    }

    /**
     * Add comment to the entity
     *
     * @param Comment $comment
     */
    public function addComment(Comment $comment)
    {
        $this->comments->add($comment);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a trait matter, it's a mapping / doctrine related problem.

Your annotation "@OneToMany" misses a configuration according to [the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional)

I guess that in your Image class, you should overwrite the property that you use for mapping.

Comment: I know than this is not a trait problem... but I'm asking if anyone knows another way to do this task or another different approach for use @ORM\OneToMany with behaviours

Comment: I think that, as the class that imports trait cannot "inject" values in the trait property's comments, it's impossible to solve with traits (as annotations aren't natives in PHP and embedded in the PHPDoc).

Comment: Do you think exist another better approach to trasform my class in Commentable with behaviours?